# Adjusting calculation of series summation to divide by n at every step of the summation

Tags: matlab, performance, series

I formerly asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54295813/performance-analysis-of-series-summation-in-matlab) question which referenced summing a series to compute pi through the formula

`pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + 1/13 ...`

Inside the computation,

`A = Sum of a_i from i=1 to N`

and

`a_i = (-1)^(i+1)/(2i-1)`

I am writing this computation to analyze the performance of the time it takes to compute pi per N summations. I want to understand the relationship between T_N and N as N increases where

`T_N = the total elapsed time it takes to do N summations.`

`N = the number of summations.`

My Matlab program plots T_N as a function of N. Inside this program, I define variables to find the values of a and b (where a is the y-intercept and b is the slope) for the following linear equation

```
T_N=a + b*N
```

To do this, I have written the following Matlab program below (with the initial test of N=1000)

```
clear all;
n=1000;
f=[];
telapsed = zeros(1,n);
tic
for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    f=[f 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed(jj) = toc;
end

hold on
plot(1:n,telapsed)
title('Time it takes to sum \pi using N summations')
xlabel('Number of summations (N)') 
ylabel('Total Time (T_N)')
p = polyfit(1:n,telapsed,1);
slope=p(1)      % slope of t_N = a + b*N or b
intercept=p(2)  % y-intercept or a
```

Running this program produces the following graph

[image]

So, this code returns the values of a and b for N = 1000. The code returns

```
a = slope = 9.3447e-06
b = intercept = 0.0011
```

So, with N=1000, I find that

```
T_n = a + b*N = 9.3447e-06 + 0.0011*N
```

I am now trying to adjust my code from plotting

```
T_N as a function of N
```

to plotting

```
(T_N − a)/N as a function of N
```

In order to do this, I have made the following adjustments

```
clear all;
n=1000;
f=[];
g=[];
telapsed = zeros(1,n);
telapsed2 = zeros(1,n);
tic

% The original for loop computes T_N as a function of N
for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    f=[f 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed(jj) = toc;
end

% I think that I need to make a new for loop to compute (T_N − a)/N as a function of N
for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    g=[g 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed2(jj) = toc/jj; % This must be wrong, I think that I need to adjust to compute (T_N − a)/N
end

hold on
plot(1:n,telapsed) % the plot for T_N as a function of N
plot(1:n,telapsed2) % the plot for (T_N − a)/N as a function of N
title('Time it takes to sum \pi using N summations')
xlabel('Number of summations (N)') 
ylabel('Total Time (T_N)')
legend('T_N as a function of N','(T_N − a)/N as a function of N')

p = polyfit(1:n,telapsed,1);
slope=p(1)      % slope of t_N = a + b*N or b
intercept=p(2)  % y-intercept or a

p2 = polyfit(1:n,telapsed2,1);
slope2=p2(1)      % Adjusted slope
intercept2=p2(2)  % Adjusted y-intercept
```

which produces the following graph

[image]

This cannot be the correct way to plot (T_N − a)/N as a function of N. I must have a mistake in defining

```
for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    g=[g 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed2(jj) = toc/jj; % This must be wrong, I think that I need to adjust to compute (T_N − a)/N
end
```

in order to compute

```
(T_N − a)/N as a function of N
```

Is there an adjustment I could make to the Matlab code above in order to compute (T_N − a)/N at the line

```
telapsed2(jj) = toc/jj;
```

I'm not sure how to correct my code so that this line computes

```
slope = slope of computation per N summations
telapsed(jj)= (toc-slope)/n
```

I might be able to add this in the first for loop for f, but I'm not sure how.

Question: How can I adjust my Matlab code so that I can successful change the computation from

```
T_N as a function of N
```

to

```
(T_N − a)/N as a function of N
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found a partial solution. I originally wrote the following code to plot T_N as a function of N.

```
clear all;
n=50;
f=[];
telapsed = zeros(1,n);
tic
for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    f=[f 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed(jj) = toc;
end

hold on
plot(1:n,telapsed)
title('Time it takes to sum \pi using N summations')
xlabel('Number of summations (N)') 
ylabel('Total Time (T_N)')
p = polyfit(1:n,telapsed,1);
slope=p(1)      % slope of t_N = a + b*N or b
intercept=p(2)  % y-intercept or a
```

Running this program produces the following graph

[image]

where

```
slope = 1.3802e-05
intercept = 0.0021
```

so,

T_N = a + b*N = 0.0021 + 1.3802e-05*N

In order to plot (T_N − a)/N as a function of N, I made the following changes

```
clear all;
n=50;
f=[];
telapsed = zeros(1,n);
tsum = zeros(1,n);
tic

for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    f=[f 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed(jj) = toc;
    psum = polyfit(jj,toc,n);
    pintercept = psum(2);
    tsum(jj) = (telapsed(jj)-pintercept)/jj;
end

hold on
plot(1:n,telapsed) % the plot for T_N as a function of N
plot(1:n,tsum) % the plot for (T_N - a)/N as a function of N
title('Time it takes to sum \pi using N summations')
xlabel('Number of summations (N)') 
ylabel('Total Time (T_N)')
legend('T_N as a function of N','(T_N - a)/N as a function of N')

p = polyfit(1:n,telapsed,1);
slope=p(1)      % slope of t_N = a + b*N or b
intercept=p(2)  % y-intercept or a
```

which produces the following plot

[image]

I'm expecting the value of (T_N − a)/N to approach a constant. I can see clearly from the above graph that the value approaches the y-intercept. The math would show me that

```
T_N = a + b*N => (T_N-a)/N = b
```

So, it appears that the adjustment made to

```
for jj=1:n
    ii=1:jj;
    f=[f 4*sum( ((-1).^(ii+1))./(2.*ii-1)  )];
    telapsed(jj) = toc;
    psum = polyfit(jj,toc,n);
    pintercept = psum(2);
    tsum(jj) = (telapsed(jj)-pintercept)/jj;
end
```

is correct.